# Adding a Resource Bundle Link to load a new Activity

Tags: android

I have a paragraph of text with a url at the end of it.  I have the text and link in the strings.xml.  Is there anyway to get it to load a new Activity from the strings.xml file?  I'm assuming I'll have to break up the paragraph text and link, but thought I'd check.

strings.xml:

        The quick brown fox can be found at: http://thequickbrownfox.com\n more text here

I need to change the hardcoded url "http://thequickbrownfox.com" to load a screen inside my app instead of a page on the web.

Comment: Can you expand your question? It's really not clear what you want to do. Even some pseudo-code might help make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings.xml is purely an abstraction mechanism used for string lookup to facilitate multi language support etc; you cannot use it to load activities or do anything else programatically.  It sounds like you are actually talking about parsing the url out of a particular paragraph stored within strings.xml and then depending on what that url is, you invoke a corresponding activity.

If this is the case then you can either parse out the url from the paragraph and respond accordingly.

OR

you can store your paragraph as one item in strings.xml and your url as another item and combine them programmatically in your code.

Either approach can be fine depending on what you are doing.